# React - onclick toggle in two different components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am facing this error, can someone help in this -
Error:
*TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')*

**Menu.tsx**

```
export const MainMenu: FC = () => {
    const [toogle, setToggle] = useState(false);
    return(
        <>
            <SubMenu />
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toogle)}>click</button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export const SubMenu: FC = () => {
    return(
        <>
           <div className="menu">
             <Image src={imgUrl} width="20" height="20" />
           </div>
           {toogle && (<span className="menu-text">{title}</span> )}  
        </>
    );
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { MainMenu} from '../Memu';

function App() {
  return (
    <MainMenu />
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: SubMenu doesnt have toogle defined

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `toggle` state to the `SubMenu` component as a prop. So:

`export const SubMenu: FC = () => {`
becomes
`export const SubMenu: FC = ({ toggle }: { toggle: boolean }) => {`
and

```
export const MainMenu: FC = () => {
    const [toogle, setToggle] = useState(false);
    return(
        <>
            <SubMenu toggle={toggle} />
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>click</button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
export const MainMenu: FC = () => {
    const [toogle, setToggle] = useState(false);
    return(
        <>
            <SubMenu toggle={toggle} />
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>click</button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export const SubMenu: FC = ({ toggle }: { toggle: boolean }) => {
    return(
        <>
           <div className="menu">
             <Image src={imgUrl} width="20" height="20" />
           </div>
           {toggle && (<span className="menu-text">{title}</span> )}  
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: i think `...FC = ({ toggle }: boolean)...` should be `({toggle}:{toggle:boolean})`

Answer (score 1):

You need pass `toggle` for `SubMenu` component

```
   export const MainMenu: FC = () => {
      const [toogle, setToggle] = useState(false);
      return(
          <>
              <SubMenu toogle={toogle} />
              <div>
                <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toogle)}>click</button>
              </div>
          </>
      );
    }
```

---

And you also have to define `interface` and then use `Props` that i used `Destructuring assignment` for `Props` so just use `toggle`:

```
    interface SubMenuProp {
      toogle: boolean
    }
    
    export const SubMenu: React.FC<SubMenuProp> = ({toogle}) => {
      return(
          <>
             <div className="menu">
               <Image src={imgUrl} width="20" height="20" />
             </div>
             {toogle && (<span className="menu-text">{title}</span> )}  
          </>
      );
    }
```

Comment: what if there is already a props - 
export const SubMenu: FC<MenuData> = ({title, href}) => {}
How to use another Props = SubMenuProp ?

Comment: Use `Extending Interfaces` like this =>   `interface SubMenuProp extends MenuData  { toogle: boolean }`

Comment: And then `SubMenuProps` will have all types of `MenuData` => `interface SubMenuProp  { toogle: boolean, title: string, href: string }`

Comment: Or if `MenuData` doesn't use anywhere except `SubMenu component` , you just need to copy all properties of `MenuData`  and put them in `SubMenuProp`